# Android Google Places: Not returning selected place

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

Followed the tutorial here.
http://www.startingandroid.com/google-places-api-tutorial-for-android/

However, when searching something in the search bar, selecting one from the suggested [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o0lw.png), then pressing the Pick Location button, the map displays the user's current location and not the place he/she selected. Can anyone provide a solution for this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder;
private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mPlacesAdapter;
private Button pickerBtn;
private AutoCompleteTextView myLocation;
private static final int PLACE_PICKER_FLAG = 1;

private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), new LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362));
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    myLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myLocation);
    mPlacesAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY, null);
    myLocation.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
    myLocation.setAdapter(mPlacesAdapter);
    pickerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerBtn);
    pickerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                Intent intent = builder.build(MainActivity.this);
                // Start the Intent by requesting a result, identified by a request code.
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_FLAG);

            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil
                        .getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), MainActivity.this, 0);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is not available.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PLACE_PICKER_FLAG:
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
                myLocation.setText(place.getName() + ", " + place.getAddress());
                break;
        }
    }
}

// Ahh
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
        = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlacesAdapter.getItem(position);
        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
        placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
    }
};

private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
        = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Log.e("place", "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                    places.getStatus().toString());
            return;
        }
        // Selecting the first object buffer.
        final Place place = places.get(0);
    }
};
}
```

**PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.java**

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {
private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutocomplete";
/**
 * Current results returned by this adapter.
 */
private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

/**
 * Handles autocomplete requests.
 */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * The bounds used for Places Geo Data autocomplete API requests.
 */
private LatLngBounds mBounds;

/**
 * The autocomplete filter used to restrict queries to a specific set of place types.
 */
private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

/**
 * Initializes with a resource for text rows and autocomplete query bounds.
 *
 * @see ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(Context, int)
 */
public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                 LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
    super(context, resource);
    mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    mBounds = bounds;
    mPlaceFilter = filter;
}

/**
 * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
 */
public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
    mBounds = bounds;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of results received in the last autocomplete query.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResultList.size();
}

/**
 * Returns an item from the last autocomplete query.
 */
@Override
public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
    return mResultList.get(position);
}

/**
 * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
 */
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                mResultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                if (mResultList != null) {
                    // The API successfully returned results.
                    results.values = mResultList;
                    results.count = mResultList.size();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most 60s
        // for a result from the API.
        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Confirm that the query completed successfully, otherwise return null
        final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                + " predictions.");

        // Copy the results into our own data structure, because we can't hold onto the buffer.
        // AutocompletePrediction objects encapsulate the API response (place ID and description).

        Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
        ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
            // Get the details of this prediction and copy it into a new PlaceAutocomplete object.
            resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                    prediction.getFullText(null)));
        }

        // Release the buffer now that all data has been copied.
        autocompletePredictions.release();

        return resultList;
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
    return null;
}

/**
 * Holder for Places Geo Data Autocomplete API results.
 */
public class PlaceAutocomplete {

    public CharSequence placeId;
    public CharSequence description;

    PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description.toString();
    }
}
}
```